# Is this a java problem or a problem with flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter

Programs that worked until a day or so ago are suddenly not "running," even if changes are as minor as changing an icon.
The error message I am getting is:

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Cannot invoke "java.io.File.getAbsoluteFile()" because "dir" is null

Unfortunately, I can't seem to get Android Studio to recognise --stacktrace, --info or --scan as "available flutter commands and options."

Android Studio, flutter, etc., are all up-to-date, and I even reinstalled java and rebooted.
Any suggestions on where I should look for solutions? is it a problem with flutter, java, or maybe my network?

Comment: Just to be clear: you're saying that you have **no** stacktrace?

Comment: Did you double check if the path that you are giving exist? Maybe you have typo there and that why you can not load your icon

Comment: No stacktrace: "Could not find an option named "stacktrace"."
With the icon, it was just typing in "help" where it had been "build" or something similar. The icon is visible beside the line numbers, it just decided not to work.

Looking at solutions that have something to do with calling "databaseFactory," but I have the feeling it is some kind of update issue: some parts are out of sync.

Comment: I don't know how I did it, or what I did, but after repeated updates, doctor, clean, etc., I somehow seem to have got it to work... and will try to rebuild on what I have.

Comment: you can execute gradle commands manually on the terminal like `./gradlew assembleDebug`. There you can add the stacktrace parameter.

Comment: Tried that:

./gradlew : The term './gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1                                                                             
+ ./gradlew assembleDebug

Answer (score 2):

Try these;

1:

> Go to pubspec.yaml file, try doing Packages get | Pub get, and then
> build the project again.

2: Try this in terminal

> flutter clean
>
> flutter pub get

3: run in your terminal

> flutter channel stable
>
> flutter upgrade --force
>
> flutter pub cache repair

next,

```
    cd <YOUR APP FOLDER>

flutter clean
```

4:

> flutter clean,
>
> flutter pub get,
>
> flutter build appbundle --release --no-tree-shake-icons

5:

> Delete your pubspec.lock, and press 'Pub Get' in your pubspec.yaml,
> it'll regenerate pubspec.lock file again and should fix the problem.

I hope one of these will work for you!!

Comment: Thanks; that worked, and just as a guess, I imagine the "delete pubspec.loc" might have done the trick, since that is the only step I hadn't tried in various ways on my own...
If the problem occurs again, I will try that first!

Comment: Hmm... worked once, and that was it.

Comment: @user8016440 problem is solved or is still it appearing?

Comment: It worked OK for a few runs, but then I had to do it again.
Went through each step, one by one, tried to run, and number 3 seems to get results.
Frustrating when all you're trying to do is debug some seemingly minor formatting issues!

Comment: run ***flutter pub global activate devtools*** and again run ***flutter pub cache repair***.

Answer (score 0):

Try These;

1:Clean and Rebuild Your Project.

> In Android Studio, try cleaning and rebuilding your Flutter project.
> Go to "Build" > "Clean Project" and then "Build" > "Rebuild Project."
> This can sometimes resolve build-related issues.

2:Check Your Project Configuration:

> Review your project's configuration files, such as pubspec.yaml, and
> make sure there are no syntax errors or inconsistencies in your
> Flutter project setup. Also, ensure that the Flutter SDK path in
> Android Studio is correctly configured.

3:Check for Changes in Dependencies:

> If you recently made changes to your project's dependencies (e.g.,
> added or updated packages), make sure that those changes are correctly
> reflected in your pubspec.yaml file. Sometimes, issues can arise from
> conflicting or outdated dependencies.

4:Check Gradle Configuration:

> Inspect your project's Gradle files (usually found in the android
> directory) to ensure there are no issues with Gradle configurations.
> Pay attention to any custom Gradle tasks or scripts that may be
> causing problems.

5:Update Flutter:

> Ensure that you are using the latest version of Flutter by running
> flutter upgrade in your terminal. Outdated Flutter versions can
> sometimes lead to compatibility issues.

6:Check Flutter Doctor:

> Run Flutter Doctor in your terminal to check for any issues with your
> Flutter installation. It will provide feedback on potential problems
> and suggest solutions.

7:Check for IDE Updates:

> Ensure that Android Studio and any Flutter-related plugins or
> extensions are up-to-date. Sometimes, updating Android Studio or the
> Flutter plugin can resolve build issues.

8:Check for System Environment Variables:

> Occasionally, issues can arise from incorrect system environment
> variables or paths. Ensure that your system's PATH variable includes
> the correct paths to your Flutter and Java installations.

9: Reimport the Project:

> In Android Studio, you can try reimporting the project. Go to "File" >
> "Invalidate Caches / Restart," and then select "Invalidate and
> Restart." This can help refresh the project's settings.

Comment: Did all of those; even rebooted.
Think what happened is that some of the updates were out of sync. Updating the SDK might be the one that tipped it, though.

Comment: And now the error is back again...

Answer (score 0):

At this point, I think it's a problem with some packages not syncing with each other, after some updates/upgrades.
I assume this should work itself out in a few days.

Comment: Still having trouble, but the "flutter clean/flutter pub get" combination now works reliably.